# How to get my output to "You rolled 2, 3, 2, 4, (ETC)"

Tags: python, random, output

The code i have so far is

```
for i in range(6):
    roll1 =int(random.randint(1,6))
    print ("You rolled",roll1)
```

I need it to print out like

```
you rolled 3,4,5,6,2
```

But my output looks like:

```
You rolled 4
You rolled 4
You rolled 1
You rolled 1
You rolled 6
You rolled 6
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
from random import randint
print( "You rolled " + ",".join(str(randint(1,6)) for j in range(6)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3, which it appears you are, you could very simply print like that printing "you rolled" and then the numbers one at a time with the print argument 'end' set to a blank string

```
print("You rolled ", end='')
for i in range(6):
    print(str(random.randint(1,6)), end='')
        if i < 5:
            print(", ", end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a comma-separated list of numbers, but you are only generating one number at a time.

You say:

```
for i in range(6):
    roll1 =int(random.randint(1,6))
    print ("You rolled",roll1)
```

> I need it to print out like

```
you rolled 3,4,5,6,2
```

First, let's try working with what you already have. Python's built-in [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function can do a lot of cool things - please do read the documentation.

First, you can use a "keyword argument" to override what `print()` outputs when it finishes printing. Normally, at the end `print()` emits a newline, but you can suppress that, or replace it:

```
print("you rolled ", end='')   # Print empty string (nothing) at end of line
```

Or, since you want a space between the words and the numbers, you could use the space as the end-of-line marker:

```
print("you rolled", end=' ')  # Note: no space at end of "rolled"
```

In either of the above cases, there **will not** be a newline printed, so whatever you put in your *next* call to `print()` will pick up at the end of the text.

Now, in your loop you generate a random number and print it. You can do that just fine. It's worth pointing out that `randint` returns an integer. It actually has the word "int" as part of the name. So you really don't need to call `int(randint`.

```
print("you rolled ", end='')

for i in range(6):
    roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(roll1, end='')
```

Now, that's not going to do what you want, because it will jam all the numbers together like "you rolled 123456". So there's a tricky problem of how to separate the numbers with commas:

```
for i in range(6):
    roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(",", roll1, end='')
```

That won't quite work, because `print()` puts a space between every two things it prints. You can override that with the `sep=` named argument.

```
    print(",", roll1, sep='', end='')
```

Even this won't quite work, since it *always* puts a comma in front of the number. That is fine, except for the very first number, but you wind up with something like "you rolled ,1,2,3,4,5,6".

Instead, you need some logic to suppress the comma.

```
for i in range(6):
    roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
    if i == 0:
        print(roll1, end='')
    else:
        print(",", roll1, sep='', end='')

print()
```

Or you need to handle one case outside the loop:

```
roll1 = random.randint(1, 6)
print("you rolled ", roll1, end='')

for i in range(5): # note: 5, not 6
     roll1 = random.randint(1, 6)
     print(",", roll1, sep='', end='')

print()
```

In general, suppressing the comma with an `if` statement is "cleaner" but pulling that outside the loop will be faster, since the `if` statement gets executed every time. This won't matter for 6 items, but it does matter if you have, say, 6 billion items.

Finally, it's worth pointing out that in this scenario, you are *forgetting* the numbers rolled as soon as you roll them. Frequently, that won't work. You might consider just "unrolling the loop" and storing 6 values in 6 variables. (I don't know if this is useful, since I don't know what problem you are trying to solve.)

In role-playing games, the dice used are frequently described as letter 'd' plus a number indicating the number of sides. A die capable of returning a number from 1-6 is a six-sided die (#sides ranges from 4 to 100). Thus, you are rolling a "d6", pronounced "dee six". Your for loop causes six such rolls, which is expressed as 6d6, "six dee six". Let's write a little function to avoid having to type so much, called `d6` because that meets the requirements for Python identifiers:

```
def d6():
    '''Return the result of rolling 1d6'''
    return random.randint(1, 6)
```

With that written, you can just say:

```
roll1 = d6()
roll2 = d6()
roll3 = d6()
roll4 = d6()
roll5 = d6()
roll6 = d6()

print("you rolled ", end='')
print(roll1, roll2, roll3, roll4, roll5, roll6, sep=',')
```